# What is the hook to remove a menu items group from Appearance > Menus column Add menu items

Tags: hooks

I want to remove the Posts menu items group from the Add menu items column in nav-menus.php screen. I tried `unregister_post_type('post');` but found out that built-in types cannot be removed.

[image: image of nav screen]

**What is the hook to get this done?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`register_post_type_args` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/) and just set the [`show_in_nav_menus` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#show_in_nav_menus) to `false`. E.g.

```php
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'my_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
function my_register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'post' === $post_type ) {
    // or use below to check against two or more post types
//  if ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'post', 'cpt_1', 'cpt_2', 'etc' ) ) ) {
        $args['show_in_nav_menus'] = false;
    }

    return $args;
}
```

And just so you know, for taxonomies (`category`, `post_tag` and custom taxonomies), you would use the [`register_taxonomy_args` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/).

Comment: A bit of curiosity has set it. When I run the filter within the `add_action('init')` it doesn't execute. I figured since `init` hook was global and is run before all, any filter should be able to process within that function. Do you know why this is the case, and is there listing of processes which cannot be in the `init`?

Comment: That is because the default post types are registered on `init` with the priority `0` which means it will run before `init` callbacks in custom plugins/themes are called. So you need to use an earlier hook such as `plugins_loaded` or `after_setup_theme`.